# AssociationTypeMisMatch: How can I create an object and associated (nested) objects with RESTful API (Rails) accepting JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, nested

I have been trying this for some hours but I cannot seem to understand what I am doing wrong. I simplified my example for demonstration purposes.

Creating the `Car` object alone works but attaching `Wheel` objects to it results in an `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMisMatch`.

Given the classes Car and Wheel

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :wheels

  validates :max_speed_in_kmh,
            :name, presence: true
end


class Wheel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :car

  validates :thickness_in_cm,
            :place, presence: true
end
```

and a CarsController

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CarsController < ApplicationController

      # POST /cars
      def create
        @car = Car.create!(car_params)
        json_response(@car, :ok)
      end

      private

      def car_params
        params.permit(
          :max_speed_in_kmh,
          :name,
          { wheels: [:place, :thickness_in_cm] }
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`echo '{"name":"Kid","max_speed_in_kmh":300,"wheels":[{"thickness_in_cm":70, "place":"front"},{"thickness_in_cm":75, "place":"rear"}]}' | http POST httpbin.org/post`

`...
    "json": {
        "max_speed_in_kmh": 300,
        "name": "Kid",
        "wheels": [
            {
                "place": "front",
                "thickness_in_cm": 70
            },
            {
                "place": "rear",
                "thickness_in_cm": 75
            }
        ]
    },
...`

The JSON is well-formed. Leaving out the wheels, the `Car` object gets created and persisted. With the `Wheel` objects though, the controller returns

`status  500
error   Internal Server Error
exception   #<ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Wheel(#70285481379180) expected, got {"place"=>"front", "thickness_in_cm"=>75} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70285479411000)>`

Comment: What is Budget here in your controller?

Comment: I forgot to rename it when I simplified my example. Fixed. I meant Car. @Rthi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a car together with wheels you need to use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Add to the Car model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :wheels` and change strong params to

```
  def car_params
    params.permit(
      :max_speed_in_kmh,
      :name,
      { wheels_attributes: [:id, :place, :thickness_in_cm] }
    )
  end
```